# HAproxy configure to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, proxy, haproxy

I am have this configuration on my HAproxy:

```
acl catalogo path_beg         /catalogo        
use_backend example.com.br-catalogo if catalogo

backend example.com.br-catalogo
balance source    
option httpclose
option forwardfor         
server example-3 192.168.0.3:82 check
```

How I make my **Laravel** app on `www.example.com.br/catalogo` works well?

Laravel is getting `/catalogo` like a route.

CSS not load `www.example.com.br/catalogo/css/styles.css`:

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php

The base URL is `/` **not** `/catalogo`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get helpful answers, please explain properly what your problem is by providing enough info. For example, you metioned that CSS os lot loaded. Please include the error message that you are encountering.

Comment: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: You might find some helpful info here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/notfoundhttpexception-in-routecollectionphp-line-161-1

Comment: Is not Laravel problem. I must a haproxy configuration like apache alias